# How to write markdown with Mathematica?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, python

Usually I typeset with Latex and Compute with *Mathematica* and then copy the outputs as Latex code and insert them in Latex, so I have to switch between Latex and *Mathematica* frequently. Thanks to the *Mathematica* notebook, I can  do both in one window.

But I'm new to *Mathematica*'s notebook interface and don't find it convenient to use. I have to switch between different styles to format my documents. I wonder is there a tool for *Mathematica* similar to IPython Notebook or RMarkdown, in which I can write with markdown in a markdown cell and compute with *Mathematica* in a code cell. Once I get the computation results, then I will use them in the following markdown cell. Remember, I want the two tasks to be done in one window.

If the tool does not exist, then can I write with IPython notebook and call *Mathematica* with Python to do computations? If I can, tell me how.

Comment: There is already a browser version of the notebook at [https://programming.wolframcloud.com/app/](https://programming.wolframcloud.com/app/). I do recognize that Markdown is a nice feature, but besides that, what else is it that you are missing?

Comment: @junyiliu Do you want to be able to export notebooks to mmd?

Comment: It's very easy to convert Mathematica Cell To Markdown.

Comment: @HyperGroups with images, inline formulas and everything else? I don't think so

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84556/how-to-export-a-mathematica-notebook-into-markdown