# Making a website with Mathematica

Tags: packages, wolfram-cloud, internet

I know [many](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) [people](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) have various websites associated with them and I'm guessing do at least some of the development of that stuff in Mathematica.

I recently fell down that rabbit hole myself, building out a [website](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/building-websites-with-mathematica.html#main-content) with Mathematica by using [pelican](https://blog.getpelican.com/) as the generator (but running pelican from within Mathematica). And I was wondering what other Mathematica-base ways there are to build out such sites.

I'm fond of the customizability of my route, but with great customizability comes great potential to majorly screw things up. Also I'm using the cloud which is known to be buggy, so it's only a matter of time before my site goes up in smoke.

I know C.E. has a [WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mathematica-toolbox/). Is that the standard route?

---

#### Update:

One other method I forgot about is that [Transmogrify](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148596/using-documentationbuild-and-transmogrify-to-generate-web-docs) was [built for this purpose](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2007/08/making-mathworld/). But I've never used it for anything other than documentation building as it seems to be a bit finnicky and takes a lot of work to use. Has else anyone used it for anything other than docs?

---

I guess my question is, what are good route for building full websites with Mathematica? They don't have to be hosted in the cloud, but to restrict the scope of this question, I'm interested in methods that use Mathematica in some integral way--i.e. to deploy the site or, at the minimum, to generate the markdown--not just to make figures.

If it's still too open ended / subject to opinion I'll see if I can restrict the scope further.

Comment: "[...] building out a website with Mathematica by using pelican as the generator [...]" -- impressive undertaking.

Comment: @AntonAntonov it was actually only ~1 days work for the actual building code because pelican is so easy to use (and `StartProcess` is too). Theme development actually took longer, because I'm not a web programmer.

Comment: @Nasser using Markdown it's not so bad, really, if you know your box forms. I never thought about using LaTeX for it (as I never bothered to learn to use LaTeX). What do you mean you write LaTeX to file as it runs, but not exporting the NB? You have selected cells styles that you save to TeX, instead of the entire NB?

Comment: @Nasser I'm afraid I don't do much "math-heavy" content, myself. I'm much more on the [chemistry side of things](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/psi4-4-mathematica.html#main-content). Mind posting your LaTeX generating method as an answer? Proper math people may find that useful.

Comment: @Nasser also how do you manager your hosting?

Comment: I have hosted localhost sites using Matematica meaning Mathematica as the server itself take a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111749/implementing-local-http-server).

Comment: @William cute. I tend to just use a `ProcessObject` link to python's SimpleHTTPServer.

Comment: Just a short comment regrading Wolfram Cloud / Wordpress plugin.
It works great for the first time you are using it, quite heavily loads your blog/site of you have many of them. However, it is absolutely unreliable. After 1-2 years of hosting they deleted my files due to some lack of credits. Now it might differs, since they change the policy from time to time.

Answer (score 15):

In my opinion, Mathematica's [XML template](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/XMLTemplates.html.en) feature makes this quite easy. You'd write your HTML code for each page using XML templates, and then populate the templates with data as necessary using `TemplateApply`. The collection of XML templates that make up the website would be what other systems call a "theme". This can be used either to build a static website offline and then deploy it, or it can be uploaded to the cloud where it might be used to dynamically generate a website based on information that the backend code pulls from databases, etc.

To make the website maintainable, recurring parts such as the menu may be put in its own XML template and then requested as needed in other parts of the website. Thus, to change the menu one would only have to change it in one place. Splitting a design into modules like this is the main idea behind most templating systems, and the fact that Mathematica's XML templates are capable of it means that they can go a long way.

WRI is pushing for XML templates to be considered for this type of website building scenarios and probably developed it with website building in mind, although they will typically say [report generation](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/string-file-html-templating/) rather than "website generation". In practice, report generation is not different from generating a website.

**EDIT**: b3m2a1 has now implemented a package that builds websites following this approach. It is available [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/Ems).

Comment: That is a very neat idea. Do you know if WRI is going to release a better NB -> XML transform system? The two of those together would make a system like pelican very simple to implement. Add some base theme to work off of and it'd be great.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Why is NB -> XML needed for this?

Comment: My assumption was that you'd write a notebook to be passed into `TemplateApply` (or some derived function) to generate a page. That's the most natural way to approach things from my perspective. The NB -> XML would happen on the backend I guess.

Comment: @b3m2a1 You mean using a notebook as a WYSIWYG editor? Well, I think you have shown, and I too in my Mathematica-to-WordPress code, that it is quite possible to convert those cell expressions that matter...

Comment: Of course. It'd just be nice to have the "official" version. Also for those who, perhaps, aren't used to working with the box language it'd be useful.

Comment: Do you know if WRI already has a base set of XML templates to extend slash if there's going to be a base function for iterating through a collection of templates? With those two features they'd beat out pelican in an instant.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I'm sorry, could you rephrase that question? I'm not sure what "extend slash if there's going to be a base function for iterating through a collection of templates" means.

Comment: sorry that's two distinct questions, I meant do you know if WRI already has a base set of XML templates to extend and do you know  if there's going to be a base function for iterating through a collection of templates.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I see now in what sense "slash" was used. I don't know about that, it feels like they are quite satisfied with what they have regarding XML features since they haven't updated it in the last few releases. The rest is up to us users I suppose.

Comment: I finally got around to implementing this so I could improve my paclet server (and other sites). Do you mind if I put a comment in the answer noting that there's a sample implementation of this out there? If you're curious [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer/main.html) is a basic example of what you can get out of it. The implementation is  mostly [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/SiteBuilder.m) and it's forked [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-SiteBuilder)

Comment: @b3m2a1 I can put a note in, but it would really help if there was a readme explaining the basics of how to use the package. Otherwise, I fear that people will not bother with it.

Comment: Done now (plus I made it a little easier to build a site). I'll put in a note about how it's basically a reimplementation of pelican once some documentation stops building in an hour or so.

Comment: FYI the link It is available here. seems dead.

Comment: Pinging @b3m2a1 regarding the link.

Comment: @chris ah I remerged that into its parent package. But the better one is now this: https://github.com/b3m2a1/Ems which uses the site builder but extends it in a few nice ways.

Comment: @b3m2a1 thanks!

Answer (score 12):

**This is not an anwser to produce live/production code for websides. (yet)**

I guess it's not what you want because its not very sophisticated but one could use MMA to make a good html code emitter directly from Mathematica Expressions.

We just write a function `html` which repeatedly calls itself on the subexpressions till it reaches "atomics" we can directly translate to html and afterward [`StringJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html)'em.

I made a small proof of concept. Theoretically this could be made into a huge library with direct intrinsic functions and normal Mathematica expressions.
(The code supports strings, unordered lists, Grids and graphics(with auto export))

```
html[params__] := 
 StringJoin["<html>\n<body>\n", html /@ List[params], 
  "\n</body>\n</html>\n"]

html[param_String] := param

html[param_List] := 
 StringJoin["\n<ul>\n", 
  StringJoin["<li>", #, "</li>\n"] & /@ (html /@ param), "</ul>\n"]

html[param_Grid] := Module[{data = param[[1]]},
  StringJoin["<table>\n", Table[
    StringJoin["<tr>\n", 
     Table[StringJoin["<td>", html[data[[rows, columns]]], 
       "</td>\n"], {columns, 1, Length[data[[rows]]]}], "</tr>\n"]
    , {rows, 1, Length[data]}], "</table>"]
  ]

html[param_Graphics] := 
 Module[{name = StringJoin[CreateUUID["plot-"], ".png"]}, 
  Export[name, param]; StringJoin["<img src=\"", name, "\"></img>"]]

html[param_] := ToString[param, InputForm]
```

This can be called with as many Mathematica expressions you want to. At example:

```
html[
 "The integral of x^2 from 0 to 1 is ",
 Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 1}],
 "\nfrom 0 to 2, 3, or 4 the integral evaluates to",
 Table[Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, i}], {i, 2, 4}],
 "\n\nThe values from sin(x) in an inteval of 0 to 3 in 0.1 steps are \
(rounded to 10^-4)",
 Grid[Transpose[Table[{x, N@Round[Sin[x], 10^-4]}, {x, 0, 3, 1/3}]]],
 "\n\nThe Plot for cos(x) is\n\n",
 Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
 ]
```

generates the coresponding code to create this webside:

[image: The generated webside]

The generated code for this is:

[image: generated code]

Annother example

```
functions = {Sin, Cos, Tan, Sqrt, RiemannSiegelZ, LegendreP[2, #] &};
html[
 Grid@Table[{functions[[i]], 
    Plot[functions[[i]][x], {x, 0, 3}, ImageSize -> 300]}, {i, 1, 
    Length@functions}]
 ]
```

[image]

Also a css style generator could be written into this whole thing. 
So if you have enough spare time, you could build awesome things in this way. 
(I feel like, this would give a nice package)

Comment: Interesting idea. I've done some similar stuff myself, but never with much sophistication. If I can make one suggestion it's to use `XMLElement`. Much easier for recursive code formatting. My package for that lives [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/WebTools.m). But as I said, it never really got off the ground.

Answer (score 12):

This small note describes the method I use. I've been using this method for years. (all of my web site is written in Latex actually, and converted to HTML. First I used to use latex2html then switched to tex4ht few years ago as it is better supported and it comes with texlive).

To use Mathematica to generate HTML, the idea is to mix Latex inside the notebook, and generate the computation result to latex file on the fly as the program runs.

[image]

This method have many advantages, but it requires one to know *some* Latex to use it.

It uses Latex as the gateway between CAS and HTML. CAS generates Latex, tex4ht converts Latex to HTML. pdflatex converts Latex to PDF.

There are mainly two method to mix CAS generated computation with Latex.

[image]

The first method is what packages such as *pythontex* uses. The second method is what I think is the better method. It is more robust.

Advantages of generating Latex from Mathematica (instead of say HTML) are many:

First, one gets a PDF file for free along the way. This is huge advantage.

Second, one gets all the features that comes with Latex/tex4ht, such as automatic table of contents generation (with HTML links to other pages), automatic href link generation from inside the document, breaking large document into many smaller HTML pages and having all the HTML links automatically generated, automatic [bibliography generated to HTML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122825/bibliography-and-tex4ht), And many more. (try to do all this with manual HTML coding :)

So *Mathematica is used only to generate Latex*. TeXForm is used heavily in this process. The rest is done by tex4ht and pdflatex if one wants pdf file as well.

I use this method all the time. As an example, I just generated [this](http://12000.org/my_notes/solving_ODE/index.htm) 300 pages document by a program I wrote in Mathematica over one week time, which Shows the  step by step solution of simple 1st order ODE's from textbooks.  Converted to HTML pages with tex4ht.

To illustrate this method, I used the example posted here.

To do this easily, CODE input cell is better suited for this than INPUT cell (since lots of Latex code  is used inside the notebook, it is easier to format using CODE cell)

I'll post the code used. Here is a [link to HTML page generated](http://12000.org/tmp/make_web_page/index.htm) and the PDF file as well and the notebook I used.  (will add small screen shot below as well)

Here is the code listing as well (same as in the above link) (this can be improved more, it was done quickly. This actually builds everything into one string. But in actual reports, I send Latex output to file immediately).

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
ClearAll[x,s];
tex[s_] := ToString@TeXForm[s];

fileName ="index.tex";
file=OpenWrite[fileName,PageWidth->Infinity];

from=0; to=1;
int=HoldForm[Integrate[x^2,{x,0,1}]];

s="
\\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\\usepackage{amsmath} 
\\usepackage{graphicx}
\\usepackage{array}
\\usepackage[letterpaper,  margin=1in]{geometry}
\\usepackage{longtable}
\\usepackage{float}
\\usepackage{hyperref}
\\begin{document}

\\ifdefined\\HCode
\\href{index.pdf}{PDF file here}
\\href{example_making_web_page.nb}{Mathematica notebook used to generate the Latex}
\\fi

\\title{Web page generated using Mathematica to Latex to tex4ht to HTML process}
\\date{\\today}
\\author{By Mathematica, Latex and tex4ht}
\\maketitle
\\tableofcontents
\\section{First example}
   The integral of $x^2$ from $"<>tex[from]<>"$ to $"<>tex[to]<>"$ is 
   \\[
      \\boxed{ " <>tex[int]<>" = "<> tex[ReleaseHold[int]]<>"}
   \\]
   From $0$ to $2 \\dots 4$ the integral evaluates to 
   \\begin{itemize}
";

  Do[
     With[{n=i},
          int=HoldForm@Integrate[x^2,{x,0,n}];
          s=s<>"\\item $"<>tex[int]<>" = "<> tex[ReleaseHold@int] <>"$\n"
     ]
    , {i,2,4}
  ];  
  s=s<>"\\end{itemize}
  The values of $\\sin(x)$ in an inteval of $0$ to $3$ in $0.1$ steps (rounded to $10^{-4}$ are 
  \\["<>
  tex[TableForm@Transpose@Table[{x,N@Round[Sin[x],10^-4]},{x,0,3,1/3}]]<>
  "\\]
  The Plot for $\\cos(x)$ is";
  p=Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},Frame->True,PlotStyle->Red,GridLines->Automatic,GridLinesStyle->LightGray];
  Export["myImage.pdf",p];
  s=s<>"
     \\begin{figure}[H]
     \\centering
        \\includegraphics[width=0.5\\textwidth]{myImage}
     \\caption{my plot of $\\cos(x)$}
     \\end{figure}
  ";

s=s<>"
     \\section{Second example}\n";
     functions = {Sin, Cos, Tan, Sqrt, RiemannSiegelZ}
     s=s<>"\\begin{center}
           %\\begin{table}
           \\begin{longtable}{|l|m{.7\\textwidth}|}\\hline \n";
     Do[
         s=s<>"$"<>tex[functions[[i]]]<>"$&";
         p=Plot[functions[[i]][x], {x, 0, 3},Frame->True,ImagePadding->20,GridLines->Automatic,GridLinesStyle->LightGray];
         imageName = "myImage"<>ToString[i]<>".pdf";
         Export[imageName,p];
         imageName = "myImage"<>ToString[i];
         s=s<>"\\includegraphics[width=0.3\\textwidth]{"<>imageName<>"}\\\\ \\hline \n"
         , 
        {i, 1, Length@functions}
     ];
     s=s<>"\\end{longtable}
           %\\caption{My table of functions}
           %\\end{table}
           \\end{center}";
     s=s<>"\\end{document}";
     WriteString[file,s];
     Close[file];
```

Running the above generates index.tex in the same folder. This file is then compiled using the command `make4ht index.tex` which generated the HTML pages.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a good workflow, if a little bit user intensive (I'm more of the type an article, save it, and click some buttons type of person). I'm sure people will find this useful. And theoretically one could use the cloud as a free host for such pages.

Comment: @b3m2a1 as I said, this is for when is doing allot of computation and one wants to generate a Latex report and HTML pages from it.  With this method, to make any changes, one simply re-run the notebook and new PDF and new web page is generated automatically.  Change an equation? re-run the notebook and get new report. It is all automatic. If one has no computation to do, then this method is not needed ofcourse.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I am a littel confused actually. If you just want to type some article and have that convert to HTML, then can I ask why you need Mathematica for? Would not just using Latex or markeup if you want be the most simple solution? Type the text, click Compile to HTML. Done. I use texstudio for this. Very good editor. Since there is no computation involved, I do not see why you need Mathematica. I assumed you want to generate a web pages content from some computation.

Comment: See [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/questions-on-the-mathematica-stack-exchange-part-2.html#main-content) as an example of what I'm dealing with. I tend to want to be able to work in a notebook and have almost exactly what I have in my notebook show up there. Markdown / LaTeX are kinda troublesome and not quite natural enough for what I generally like to do. Plus I usually have Mathematica running and do my explorations there anyway.

Comment: `and have almost exactly what I have in my notebook show up there` OK, I am still little confused. If all what you want is convert a notebook to HTML, then why not simply hide all the cells you do not want to show up, then just click on `File->Save As->Web page` ?  Then upload the HTML page to your web page? But this is too obvious, so I must still be not understanding clearly what is it exactly you are trying to automate :)

Comment: The big thing is that I wanted a full *site* not just a page. Sites allow you to have themes, landing pages, etc. and building all that stuff out by hand is tedious. As it is, my flow is: write, save, click a "Build Pages" button that pushes site building to pelican and if I'm good with the preview, click a "Deploy Site" button that uploads new content to the cloud. It took some package building, but it's clean and extensible. I was mostly interested in a) whether people had pure Mathematica ways that were better and b) what other methods existed, so others would have a good listing of options

Comment: Also the NB -> HTML "Save As..." tends to be glitchy in my experience.

Comment: @b3m2a1 There are plenty of  web site builder tools (I will never use any of them, since I need to be able to control everything myself.) but for some, they work. I really do not think you need Mathematica in this case for this. Mathematica is not a web site builder tool. Mathematica is good at computation, and generating Latex from. Any way, I showed the method I use.  Good luck.

Comment: I actually have a site that I build entirely within Mathematica using one of said tools (pelican). The question was to see what else was out there. Definitely a useful answer for all the mathematicians around. I'm sure someone will take advantage of it.

Answer (score 10):

I thought I'd just briefly lay out what I do so people don't have to go to the link to my blog post in the question. The packages for all this junk are [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/WebTemplating.m), [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/WebTools.m), and [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/PyTools.m). Look for the things with `Pelican` and `Py` starting their names and the `WebSiteDeploy` function. The autodoc pages are [here](http://www.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/b3m2a1.docs/reference/BTools/guide/PyToolsPackage.html), [here](http://www.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/b3m2a1.docs/reference/BTools/guide/PyToolsPackage.html) and [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.docs/reference/BTools/ref/WebSiteDeploy.html)

#### Step 1: pelican

I wrote a [venv](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) wrapper, installed [pelican](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/wiki/Powered-by-Pelican) using that via pip, setup up a Mathematica palette to handle making new sites and posts, made a theme, etc.

#### Step 2: Notebook to Markdown

Then I wrote a Notebook to Markdown converter because pelican can handle Markdown. Basically all complex box forms get rasterized. Math forms will be included once I finally get around to writing something about discrete variable representation and need them. Pre-rasterization future file names are checked against existing ones to avoid unnecessary rasterize calls.

#### Step 3: Site Deployment

Using that same venv wrapped I call pelican's build process, then deploy the new content using [`WebSiteDeploy`](http://www.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/b3m2a1.docs/reference/BTools/ref/WebSiteDeploy.html)

#### Step 4: Palettes / Stylesheets

I also built out a stylesheet that also saves to Markdown when a standard `{"MenuCommand", "Save"}` is called and a palette for the build processes, new file making, stuff finding, etc.

It's overkill and with a bit of work C.E.'s version is clearly a better way to do the same in the future. But it's good to have out here, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my second method, based on C.E.'s idea of using [`XMLTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/XMLTemplate.html).

I've detailed exactly what I did [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/building-websites-with-mathematica-part-2.html)

[This](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer/main.html) is a site that I built with my generator

My process basically went as follows:

#### 1. XMLTemplates

For your site theme, you need to define a collection of `XMLTemplate` files. You can see one of these [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Resources/Themes/b3m2a1/templates/base.html).

For new sites I just branch off of that

#### 2. XMLTemplate function library

This allowed me to greatly simplify the quantity of code I had to right. My lib of functions can be found [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/tree/master/Resources/Themes/template_lib/include/lib).

The framework that creates the site exposes these by default

#### 3. Write extractor for XMLObject

This involved pulling both metadata and content from a the [`XMLElements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/XMLElement.html). That basically just required a few `Cases` calls

#### 3a. Write Markdown to HMTL converter

I already had notebook to markdown, so then I had to write markdown to `XMLObject`. This is incomplete. If you have a more complete implementation, please add it as an answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154634/38205)

#### 4. Create site-data cache

I defined a standard symbol that caches all of the data for a given site. This is then used in the [`XMLTemplates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/XMLTemplate.html).

#### 5. Generate all site content

This just outputs to a standard directory, like pelican does

#### 6. Deploy

Same as what I did with pelican

Answer (score 1):

There is an exact solution you are looking for

Pure Wolfram Engine (freeware!) [Webserver](https://github.com/KirillBelovTest/HTTPHandler) with many features supported like WebSockets, GET/POST (but no TLS support so far).

[Template engine](https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/wlx) that let you write in Wolfram Language XML (a superset of XML and WL) web-applications with data-binding, dynamics and real-time calculations.

I would not recommend to use webserver with a public access granted since it might introduce some license issues, but rater utilize Template engine to generate files and host them at Github pages for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I use Mathematica to convert from a subset of LaTeX to html. (see [symmeticfunctions.com](http://symmetricfunctions.com/) )
While parsing the document, I also keep track of some meta-data, so that hyperref-style links works, and create an indes. Also, I parse \cite-commands, and generate the bibliography at the bottom on each page. This uses the same .bib file as I use when doing research.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer and provide a working example? - very interested!

Comment: The link above is the working example... for example, you can browse the page on Schur polynomials: http://symmetricfunctions.com/schur.htm (I have a github with a Mathematica package for computing with symmetric functions, btw)