# Building a GitBook with Mathematica

Tags: web-access, development, publishing

GitBook is a fun little website that will take Markdown source material and build a little book out of it.

How can I use Mathematica to build a GitBook with a minimum of effort?

Answer (score 20):

#### tl;dr

This is really quite easy with a toolkit I've been building; [this](https://b3m2a1.gitbooks.io/gitbook/content/) is an example of a GitBook I built with these tools.

---

#### Preface

This answer is gonna build off some stuff I've been developing off-and-on for the past few months. Everything is packaged up and most of it is in a palette, so you'll be able to do this with minimal effort.

It started with [my attempts to build websites with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152663/38205). That turned out to be a decent success. [This Mathematica tutorial](https://www.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/b3m2a1.testing/tutorial/main.html) is an example of a fun, non-trivial website I built with Mathematica.

Then halirutan brought [GitBook](https://www.gitbook.com) to my attention and I realized I could adapt that quickly to my needs.

First I took my tutorial website and [built a GitBook out of it](https://b3m2a1.gitbooks.io/mathematica-tutorial/content/).

But now I've done that one better and generalized that framework entirely, [packaging up my GitBook builder](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/GitBookBuilder.wl).

Here's how we do this. It's really quite easy, although there is some minimal book-keeping involved.

### Book Development

It may seem like there are many steps here, but most of them are so fast and boiler-plate that by using the palettes and templates I provide you can get a GitBook up and running in about 5 minutes (excluding the time it takes to actually write your content)

#### Initializing a website

My system builds off my work making a website builder, so to start I make a website that I simply never build an deploy.

I have a site-builder palette, which can be used to make a new one and add content. Alternately, you can simply copy down the content I have [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-gitbook/tree/master/src/content) and just build off of it.

#### Writing our content

For this sample GitBook I poached the content from the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) to show that this system can do things beyond Mathematica code.

To make the content we use [a stylesheet I developed for writing Markdown](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/MarkdownNotebook.nb) websites, which requires that one has installed my package [BTools](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools).

These notebooks are basically the same as any notebook:

[image: asd]

`"Text"` cells get exported as plain text, `"Code"` cells get exported as code, etc.

There are also a bunch of custom cell types built-in with different export behaviors, all linked together via `StyleKeyMapping` for ease of access.

#### Book-keeping and Metadata

The only thing that's really different is a metadata block that's put at the top of the notebook (the style for which is accessed via <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>:

[image: meta]

This is used by pelican and my site builder, and we'll use it again here for setting up the [GitBook SUMMARY.md](https://toolchain.gitbook.com/pages.html)

The main things we need for that are the `"ID"` and `"Path"` parameters. The `"Path"` gives the section it should be nested under and the `"ID"` gives the sorting in standard versioning syntax.

As an example, here's the used metadata [for one page](https://b3m2a1.gitbooks.io/gitbook/content/2-using-the-interpreter/1-invoking-the-interpreter.html):

```
<|
 "Title" -> "Invoking the Interpreter",
 "Path" -> "Using the Python Interpreter/Invoking the Interpreter",
 "ID" -> "2.1"
 |>
```

And here is the the same for [the following page](https://b3m2a1.gitbooks.io/gitbook/content/2-using-the-interpreter/1-invoking-the-interpreter/1-argument-passing.html):

```
<|
 "Title" -> "Argument Passing",
 "Path" -> "Using the Python Interpreter/Invoking the Interpreter",
 "ID" -> "2.1.1"
 |>
```

We see that in a given section of the book all that really changes is the `"ID"` (which doesn't even have to be in a list like that) and the `"Title"`.

#### Creating the Intro Page

All of my websites have an About page to them, so I just use that as the [GitBook README](https://toolchain.gitbook.com/structure.html)

So you'll have to add an About page under the pages directory of the site. Again the easiest thing is likely just to copy the sample site I have and edit that About page.

### Building the Site

With the content part of the equation handled we can now actually get the book deployed.

I've written [a package for this](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/GitBookBuilder.wl), but I'll do a quick walkthrough of the requisite steps.

#### Copying content

First we simply copy over the content from the site to our build directory. I take all of the md files from the `"posts"` directories of the site we've built, stripping the metadata, and anything else in the `"content"` directory

#### Creating the README.md

This is build from the `"pages/About.md"` file, stripping all of the metainfo first. I simply export that to a top-level `"README.md"` file

#### Creating the SUMMARY.md

This was the only at-all-challenging part of the whole endeavor. First I extract all of metainfo, then I sort this by `"ID"`, group it by path components, build a new markdown notebook from these parts, and call `NotebookMarkdownSave` on that.

#### Setting up the GitHub Repo

Finally, all one needs to do is initialize a GitHub remote, initialize git on the book directory, and push that to GitHub.

### Package-Level Flow

None of the preceding steps actually need to be done by hand, though. I have two functions in the package I linked to before, `GitBookBuild` and `GitBookPush`.

The first builds a GitBook from the site directory, and is called like so:

```
build = FileNameJoin@{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "GitHub", 
    "mathematica-gitbook"};

GitBookBuild[
  FileNameJoin@{$WebSiteDirectory, "gitbook"},
  build
  ];
```

The second will initialize the git repo, and can use the GitHub API to initialize a GitHub repo too. That's called like this:

```
remote =
  "https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-gitbook";

GitBookPush[build, remote]
```

When all of this is done we get a [GitHub repo like this](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-gitbook):

[image: gitbook]

Everytime you edit the source, simply call `GitBookBuild` and `GitBookPush` again and it'll push the changes.

### Setting up the GitBook

The last step is just to go to [gitbook.com](https://www.gitbook.com), make an account, and make a new book that loads from the GitHub repo.

After the smoke clears, you get a [nice new GitBook](https://b3m2a1.gitbooks.io/gitbook/content/):

[image: gitbook]