# Book/tutorial-writing strategies

Tags: document-creation

As a kind of follow-up to [my question on making websites](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152663/making-a-website-with-mathematica), I'm looking for strategies for writing and distributing chaptered, sectioned content in Mathematica. To my eyes this is analogous to a book or tutorial. I've done this before [here](https://mresources.github.io/tutorial/) but that took a bit of work to organize and curate and I'd like to have something where I can rapidly churn something out if I have an idea.

My basic sense of what I'm looking for here is:

- the content at least should be writable entirely within Mathematica
- it should be easy to distribute in an easily navigable way or standard distribution format
- the distributed product should look good
- I shouldn't need to think too much or remember many steps

I'll post my current strategy for this at some point soon, but I want to get the community's take first.

Comment: Wolfram Research has a template for crafting books in *Mathematica*, used by Stephen Wolfram and others.  Contact them for a template.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork that'd be fun to look at. I will definitely do so and maybe write up something about it here and how it works if they let me.

Comment: Check out https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1429739

Comment: @ChrisK Ah... I see. That was disappointing. Not a very powerful template/system. All the distribution and indexing and everything appears to still be on the user side.